# Running Behat with Selenium2Driver in combination with Homestead

Tags: php, selenium, laravel, behat

I have a Homestead installation running with Behat to test my Laravel project. I am running into some problems when using the `@javasccript` tag to run my tasks as Selenium.

I have downloaded Selenium standalone server on my Windows host machine. Its version is 2.42.2

In my behat.yml i have got the following configuration:

```
default:
    extensions:
     Behat\MinkExtension:
         base_url: http://my.app:8000/
         sessions:
            default_session:
                goutte: ~
            selenium_session:
                selenium2:
                      wd_host: http://x.x.x.x:4444/wd/hub/static/resource/hub.html
    suites:
        functional:
            paths:    [ %paths.base%/features/functional ]
            contexts: [ LaravelFeatureContext ]
```

However when I run my scenarios I get the following error:

> Given I am on the "/users/create" page    #
>   LaravelFeatureContext::iAmOnThePage()
>         Could not open connection: Curl error thrown for http POST to http://x.x.x.x:4444/wd/hub/static/resource/hub.html/session with
>   params: {"desiredCapabilities":{"tags":["homestead","PHP
>   5.6.0-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1"],"browserName":"firefox","version":"21","platform":"ANY","browserVersion":"9","browser":"firefox","ignoreZoomSetting":"false","name":"Behat
>   feature suite","deviceOrientation":"portrait","deviceType":"tablet"}}
>
> ```
>   Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 4444: Connection refused (Behat\Mink\Exception\DriverException)
> ```

When i go to `http://x.x.x.x:4444/wd/hub/static/resource/hub.html` I see that the selenium hub is up and running.

Could the issue here be that I am running Behat from the homestad terminal through SSH and that does not resolve to the IP address of the hub? Because the ip address of the host is `localhost`

How can I solve this?

Comment: Didn't see the last line of your question. No that isn't a problem, the problem is the local browser in Homestead... i.e. there isn't one. Have you considered using a headless browser such as PhantomJS?

Comment: @DavidBarker Do you mean that I should install a browser in homestead? That doesn't sound right to me. I want the browser to start on my host machine, which is windows

Comment: No I'm not suggesting you install a browser in homestead, the only one that would work would be a headless one. Mink is attempting to start a firefox session on the homestead box... that is the problem here.

Comment: @DavidBarker so the quesion is, How could I solve this? How to ensure that the box is getting started on the windows host.

Comment: This is why I left a comment, I haven't got an answer for you only that I wanted to let you know exactly what the problem is.  I can't see any way to actually make this possible without using a headless browser to run the tests on. If you want to have a full browser you may have to run the tests locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the answer myself.

In `behat.yml` i had to change the config of `wd_hub` to `http://192.168.178.26:4444/wd/hub` and then it works.